# Balance partition a dataset with n weighted features

Tags: machine-learning

I have a dataset with 10 million rows. Each row has different feature- say feature1..feature10 Each feature can be represented by double value for each row. I need to partition this dataset into n clusters, ideally n should be less than 10. I want all the clusters to be as balanced as possible. I should be able to define during balancing what should be weight of each feature. For example: one way to say that is : Distribute the dataset into 3 clusters such as each feature is as balanced as possible. Other way can be : feature1 takes more weightage than feature2, and balancing should take care of weights.

I am complete newbie to the field and I  believe that there is already readymade solution to solve problems like this. Please be as elaborate as possible.